# JuJu manual provisioning

Tags: juju

I added a machine several times form my projects with juju in my manual cloud (mixing virtual and physical nodes). Everything was working fine until now where status shows me :

ERROR error checking if provisioned: subprocess encountered error code 1 (Failed to issue method call: No such method 'ListUnitFiles')

I read about this [..error away if the systemd-services package is installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1472009) and this [machine already provisioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433842/how-to-resolve-error-machine-is-already-provisioned-in-manual-provision-set-up) and tried to fix the error, unsuccessfully. I'm using juju 2.1.2

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, I removed Systemd packages,then I was able to add machine with no problem.

It could be related to the fact that Systemd is not supported for a 14.04 machine.